# C-Segmentation Fault error

Tags: c

Recently i have started working on built-in functions but came up with an error and that is:

Why am i getting **segmentation fault** for this program

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
int main()
{
    char str[50];
    int n;
    printf("Who is your best friend? ");
    scanf("%s",str);
    n=isalpha(str);
    if(n!=0)
    {
        printf("Is Alpha");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Invalid Input");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please help me out...

Comment: Compile your code with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Improve your code to get no warnings. Then [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/)

Comment: Also read the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c), notably of each function you are using (because you use them wrongly)

Comment: For a start: `isalpha` takes a `char` as a parameter not an array of `char`s.  Also this code has nothing to do with recursion.

Answer (score 4):

[`isalpha()`'](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha)s prototype is

```
int isalpha( int ch );
```

The argument is of type `int`. But the one that you are passing is of type `char *` since `str` is a character array.

Perhaps you meant

```
unsigned char str;
scanf("%c",&str);
```

`isalpha()` returns `0` if its argument is *not* alphabetic.

And to avoid overflow, you could modify your `scanf()` to

```
scanf("%49s",str);
```

with one character to store the `\0` character.

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24746111/scanf-field-width-string-overflow) post.

Edit: The argument of `isalpha()` shouldn't be `char`. It must be at least `unsigned char` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6693878/5375464). Thanks to [melpomene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1848654/melpomene) for pointing this out.

Comment: Even with `char`, you need `isalpha((unsigned char)ch)` to avoid undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Edited.

Comment: Even tough after correction in scanf statement it's still not satisfying my output. Because when i have given an input "gh23s" the program giving me an output "Is Alpha" but i should get "Invalid Input"...

Comment: @ShubhamKumarSingh Did you fix the call to `isalpha`? How?

Comment: Sorry @melpomene I didn't get you..Can you give me a clarity...